# Action is not performed when clicking ComboBox and Button

Tags: c#, button, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I'm totally new into forms and I have an problem.
I would like to choose one of items in comboBox then hit button and my action regarding to chosen item is performed. 
I'm creating list with options, boolean to check if button was hit and integer index.

```
List<string> options = new List<string> {"Dodaj studenta", "Wyświetl studenta", "Edytuj studenta" };
private bool button1WasClicked = false;
int index;
```

I'm trying to read index from comboBox:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Setting handle to button to change the value of boolean to true when user hits button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1WasClicked = true;
}
```

And setting the comboBox:

```
private void comboBoxSetup()
{ 
    this.comboBox1.DataSource = options;
    this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; //read only
    if(index == 0 && button1WasClicked == true)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("My message here");
    }
 }
```

PS: In constructor I have comboBoxSetup(); :)

When I'm checking only index in  condition - popup is visible. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: If `comboBoxSetup` is called from the constructor, that code is executing before index is set to anything

Comment: You are right! I moved whole code from comboBoxSetup() into button and it worked! Thank you for showing other point of view - I thought that I made some miskate in creating comboBox or checking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Plutonix the solution that worked:

Insted of calling comboBoxSetup() in constructor I moved whole code from this method to

> button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)